# Unity aircraft physics

Tags: unity, c#, physics, mathematics

I want to make a simple aircraft controller, what looks like little realistic in unity. I watch some video from airplane physics. and make a simple script in unity, but if I start, my plane cant move or if I change drag to zero, it cant lift. I tried to use real data and get it from wiki(F22 Raptor). To my game object, I gave the rigidbody component mass = 19670 kg. 
Engine thrust = 2 * 116000.0f Newton.

```
    private void calculateEnginePower()
    {
        EnginePower = engineThrust * ThrottleInput;
    }

    private void calculateForces()
    {
        angleOfAttack = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, rb.velocity);
        angleOfAttack = Mathf.Clamp(angleOfAttack, 0, 90);

        coefficient = Mathf.Pow(1225.04f * rb.velocity.magnitude, 2) - 1; //M^2-2 where: M is mach.         

        if (coefficient > 0.0f)
            coefficientLift = (4 * angleOfAttack) / Mathf.Sqrt(coefficient);
        lift = 1.2754f * 0.5f * Mathf.Pow(rb.velocity.magnitude, 2) * coefficientLift * 78.04f; // densy1.2754 kg/m3, speed m/s , (F22)Wing area: 840 ft² (78.04 m²)

        coefficientDrag = 0.021f;
        rb.drag = coefficientDrag * 0.5f * Mathf.Pow(rb.velocity.magnitude,2) * 1.2754f * 78.04f;

        rb.AddForce(transform.up * lift);
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * EnginePower);
    }
```

roll, pitch... inputs from keyboard and mouse, EnginePower, RollInput... are simple properties and I call the Move function in a controller inside void Update.

```
Move(float roll, float pitch, float yaw, float throttle)
{ 
// transfer input parameters into properties.s 
RollInput = roll; 
PitchInput = pitch; 
YawInput = yaw; 
ThrottleInput = throttle; 
AirBrakes = false; 
calculateEnginePower();
calculateForces(); 
calculateRotation(); 
}
```

used these formulas:

for Lift force:
[Lift formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WARcq.png)
for Lift coefficient:
[Cl formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Akw.png)
for Drag:
[Drag formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54IHk.png)
and for Drag coefficient: I used data from wiki too (0.021f).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction

Ah no, I'm afraid that this won't work. You decided to get to an intriguing yet difficult realm. Calculating accurately \$C_L\$ and \$C_D\$ is not easy (there wouldn't be aerodynamic tunnels if it was).

Also I would suggest to try modeling much older aircraft (of the Cold war era like F-86 or Mig-17). Getting aerodynamic information for fighters like F-22 is virtually impossible (they are classified). I've heard that for some few of the older jets some aerodynamic figures have been declassified but I can't find any information right now. You can search in [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com) or ask if it's not already asked.

Having said that, let's look into your problems:

### Why can't I accelerate

You are setting the value you calculated for the *aerodynamic drag* to `rb.drag`. That won't work. Unfortunately [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) isn't clear as in what drag represents. As I get it is aerodynamic drag which is dimensionless. You set newtons there so I guess drag will be so high that your aircraft is trying to swim not fly. So you have 2 options:

1. Set `rb.drag` to zero and call

   ```
   float drag = coefficientDrag * 0.5f * Mathf.Pow(rb.velocity.magnitude,2) * 1.2754f * 78.04f;
   rb.AddForce(transform.forward * (EnginePower - drag));
   ```
2. or simply do `rb.drag = coefficientDrag;` and then let unity handle it.

The first gives you more control while the second relies on unity's computations that I am unfamiliar with.

### Why can't I takeoff

Well that's simpler: you use a formulae that applies to supersonic speeds

$$
C_{L} = \frac{4α}{\sqrt{M^2 - 1}}
$$

Clearly if \$M < 1\$ then the radicand becomes negative and the root can't be calculated. Your code ignores it. So `coefficientLift` will be `0` (I guess, you don't show the initialization). That means that you won't get any lift until you get supersonic. Ouch. You need a big runway for that.

One thing you can do, is to create a text file (in a format of your preference) that will represent a "typical" \$C_L - AoA\$ matching. One example you can use is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_coefficient)

[image: AoA vs CL]

You can have something like

```
#AoA  CL
-5    0
-3    0.25
-0.5  0.5
2     0.75
```

and so on, and then apply linear interpolation to get the values in between.

### Other remarks

You use rb.velocity.magnitude as both velocity and Mach number. You need to make conversions (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_number#Calculation)):
$$
M = \frac{u}{c}
$$

```
where:
M is the Mach number
u is velocity of the moving aircraft and
c is the speed of sound at the given altitude
```

Hope the above helps. Good luck with your game.